# Questions for strong and weak LLN (The law of large numbers)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

Questions for strong and weak LLN (The law of large numbers)

1. The expectation values of X1,X2,...,Xn be can not be inifinite, right?
2. Variances of X1,X2,...,Xn can be infinite, right?

Reference:

1. The arithmetic mean is approximate to E(X1)=E(X2)=...
2. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: Yes. Actually one can conclude that even if you do not have finite mean, but $E X = \infty$, then $n^{-1}(X_1+\dots X_n) \to \infty$ with probability 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strong law of large numbers states $n^{-1}(X_1+\dots+X_n)\to E X_1$ almost surely if $X_n$ are i.i.d and $E \lvert X_1 \rvert<\infty$. We will show the converse.

Suppose $n^{-1}(X_1+\dots +X_n)$ converges almost surely to a finite limit. Then
$$\left \lvert \frac{X_1+\dots +X_{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{n}\right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac{nX_{n+1}-X_1-\dots-X_n}{n(n+1)}\right \rvert \to 0$$
In other words,
$$\left \lvert \frac{X_{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{n(n+1)}\right \rvert \to 0$$, implying $X_n/n \to 0$ almost surely. Now, $ E\lvert X_1 \rvert <\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n\geq 0}P(\lvert X \rvert > n)<\infty$. Indeed, $$E \lvert X_1 \rvert = \sum_{n\geq 0} P(\lvert X_n \rvert > n) = \sum_{n\geq 0}P(\lvert X_n \rvert /n >1)<\infty$$
, where the convergence of the sum follows by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma and the fact that $X_n/n \to 0$ almost surely.

There is another generalization of the strong law, which can be proved. Let $E X^+ = \infty$ and $EX^- <\infty$. Then $n^{-1}(X_1+\dots+X_n)\to \infty$ almost surely. Put $Y_n^{(M)} = 1_{(-\infty,M]}(X_n)X_n$. It's not hard to complete the proof from here.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982659/mean-sample-convergent-to-infinity-almost-surely) for details.

Finally, if $X_n$ has finite variance, then $n^{-1}(X_1+\dots+X_n)\to E(X_1)$ in $L^2$ (as well as almost surely). This follows trivially as $E(n^{-1}S_n - E X)^2 = Var(n^{-1}S_n) = n^{-1}Var \,X \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence $S_n/n \to E X$ in $L^p$ for $1\leq p \leq 2$ also.

Comment: 1. So you mean that for strong LLN and weak LLN, both of them can have infinite expectation values and infinite variances, right? 2. But if the expectation values are infinite, then the arithmetic mean will approximate to infinity, right? 3.Moreover, if the variances are infinite, is there any important results related to it? (For example, arithmetic mean will approximate to infinity) Sorry, I just want to apply the probability theory's thing to statistics, so you can just give me the brief answers.(Yes/No answer is the best. I don't need rigorous proof for these questions.)

Comment: 1) and 2). Yes, but be careful you understand what it means for expectation to be infinite. It means $E X^+ = \infty$ XOR $E X^-=\infty$, where $X^+ = \max(X,0)$ and $X^- =\max(-X,0)$. In particular, nothing I said applies to Cauchy random variable. 3) As far as I know, no, but I am also just an undergraduate ...